# Why does the ReSharper 8 test runner crash on this spec?

Tags: c#, resharper, mspec

I have a set of tests running using MSpec. The first two run ok, but when I include the third test, the test runner crashes with a NullReferenceException before running any of the tests:

```cs
Because of = () => _result = Subject.GetReport(fooReportType);

It should_return_a_success = () => _result.Successful.ShouldBeTrue();
It should_return_something = () => _result.Data.ShouldNotBeNull();

// this test crashes
It should_return_a_concrete = _result.Data.ShouldBeOfType<IReportBase<BarChart>>;
```

I'm running:

- VS 2013 RC
- ReSharper version 8.0.2000.2660
- Machine.Specifications 0.5.16 (according to NuGet)

I've tried replaing the type in `ShouldBeOfType` with `ReportBase<BarChart>,` the implementation of the interface as well as a concrete extension of `ReportBase<BarChart>,` all with the same result.

Comment: Did you literally copy this from your editor or did you maybe type it incorrectly? You're missing the proper delegate assignment `= () =>` and the method call parens on the end of the `ShouldBeOfType<T>()`

Comment: And, sorry, I should have explained in my edit, but I uncommented the test so that it would color nicely (easier to catch bad formatting that way).

Comment: Anthony, I'm upping your comment, even though it will be of no use to anyone but me. You are correct! Man, we had a couple people look at that, but we were getting hung up on the apparent crash of the test runner. Dopeslaps for me. :-)

Comment: I figured out a way to make it an answer and complain about resharper in general ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with ReSharper, especially when it comes to invoking the test runner. It doesn't always run the compiler and, even when it does, it can use some goofy, out-of-date shadow copies. You're gonna want to double-check your syntax...

```
It should_return_a_concrete = _result.Data.ShouldBeOfType<IReportBase<BarChart>>;
```

You're missing the delegate assignment, `= () =>`, and the method invocation parens at the end of the `ShouldBeOfType<T>()`.